# Google Glass does not appear on Android Studio devices

Tags: android-studio, google-glass

I want to develop for Google Glass with Android Studio. I'm really new to it. When I connect Google Glass to my computer over USB, Android Studio does not recognize it ("no connected devices").

Android Studio recognizes when I'm connecting my mobile over USB, and my computer recognizes the glasses, but Android Studio cannot find the connection to the glasses. I of course enabled debugging on the glasses, and it's connected to my mobile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify your question to indicate what operating system you're running Android Studio on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I posted about it earlier this year on the Glass Explorers forum to ask for some help. I got a couple of responses, tried them, and this is what worked for me, posted by [Kevin](https://www.glass-community.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/8103)

"Are you running Windows? If so open the device manager and see what Glass is listed as, if it has an exclimation point right click and update driver software choose to search your computer for the driver and point it too the sdk>extras > google_usb folder (assuming you have updated the drivers in the sdk manager recently.

After this is done reboot the pc plug your Glass in let it install the drivers and if it is working properly you may get a prompt on Glass to trust this computer for debugging.. If this didnt work.

Go back to the device manager, glass should now be listed as an android adb device. Now click on this and choose to update driver software, then instead of pointing the the google_usb folder, click on the part below that "let me pick from a list of device drivers on my pc.."  When you do this choose composite usb device and then it should recognize the Glass in adb. "

I hope this helps.

EDIT:

Another thing to try:

You need to make sure that you have the right drivers. The issue for me was that I needed to open the SDK manager and download the USB Drivers - go try that.

Comment: thanks. I dont quite understand. In the device manager. Where does the glass suppose to be listed? Tab device definition or Tab Android Virtual device?  at "Device definition" I didnt find any google glass. There are "androd wear round" and "Android wear square". Under "android virtual devices" there is only one device, but thats an amulator I created before for mobile. So Im not sure exactly what Im looking for

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the right drivers. The issue for me was that I needed to open the SDK manager and download the USB Drivers - go try that.